# "Number points" in a test - How to say that?

Tags: translation

What is the best way to talk about the number points indicated in a test to give a note like 12/20 ? In France, we say "barème".

Comment: It would help for you to add some English explanations about those *points*. For example, are they *percentage points*, or issues *pointed out*, or specific *questions* on the test?

Comment: You're totally right. That has been done.

Comment: You can call them your *marks*.

Comment: Does "scoring" is a a good way to talk about all the marks ?

Comment: You can say you got a *score* of 12 out of 20, or that you got 12 *marks*.

Comment: In American English you will not hear the word "marks" in this context.  Use "you got a score of 12 out of 20 points" on this side of the pond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

- you got 12 *marks* out of a possible 20; or
- you got a *score* of 12 out of 20.

> **mark** *noun*
>   3 *British* A point awarded for a correct answer or for proficiency in an examination or competition.
>   ‘Students are awarded marks out of seven for each paper, and get a final overall score.’
>   ‘I know of a professor who was in the habit of deducting marks in examinations for bad spelling, poor grammar or clumsy sentences.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/mark)
>
> **score** *noun*
>   1.2 A rating or grade, such as a mark achieved in a test.
>   ‘Test scores increase, reading levels rise, and teachers report fewer disciplinary problems.’
>   ‘Total the three scores on each line to get your totals.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/score)